# Why does the rule executes multiple times in the context of an object?

Tags: workflow-foundation, chaining, rule-engine

There is a container class which has a collection of integers. My objective is to calculate the sum of all the integers. I am using the workflow rule engine here. The two rules written are somewhat like follows:

```
RuleName: Initializer
Priority: 2
Condition : 1==1
ThenActions: 
    this.i = 0;
ReEvaluationBehavior: Always

----

RuleName: Looping
Priority: 1
Condition: this.i < this.Items.Count
ThenActions:
    this.total = this.total + this.Items[this.i];
    this.i = this.i + 1;
ReEvaluationBehavior: Always
```

This is just an abstract representation. The Container class is defined as:

```
public class NumberContainer
{
    public int i;
    public int ItemCount 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Items.Length;
        }

        private double total;

        public double Total
        {
            get { return total; }
            set { total = value; }
        }

        private double[] items;

        public double[] Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { items = value; }
        }

        //Other stuff...
    }
}
```

I've only shown the important fields here. All of this (i.e the populated container object and the ruleset) is fed to the rule engine to execute.

Why does the `Looping` rule execute multiple times whereas `Initializer` rule only executes once? Is it something to do with Chaining? Is it the fact that we are setting the value of `i` in the `Looping` rule, and the same variable happens to be a part of the corresponding rule's condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically RETE-based/forward-chaining rules engines execute a rule whenever its condition becomes "newly true".  Newly true in this context means that the condition is true and that one of its input variables has been changed since the last time the condition was checked.

In your case, the first rule has no input variables and hence is fired only once.  The second rule has two input variables, `this.i` and `this.Items.Count`.  After it is fired first, the second rule modifies `this.i`, causing its condition to be rechecked after firing the rule.  The condition is then newly true again (repeating then until `this.i>=this.Items.Count`).